# Please I accidently removed python3.8 file from /usr/bin how can I restore it

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3

this is the error I get when install python3.8 or running python

```
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f6b1e8a6740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-webencodings (--configure):
 installed python3-webencodings package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python3-psutil (5.5.1-1ubuntu4) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fb94be12740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-psutil (--configure):
 installed python3-psutil package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of resetter:
 resetter depends on python3-psutil (>= 3.4.1); however:
  Package python3-psutil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package resetter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-html5lib:
 python3-html5lib depends on python3-webencodings; however:
  Package python3-webencodings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-html5lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-lxml:amd64 (4.5.0-1ubuntu0.3) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f4941806740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-lxml:amd64 (--configure):
 installed python3-lxml:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python3-soupsieve (1.9.5+dfsg-1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f59b8207740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-soupsieve (--configure):
 installed python3-soupsieve package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-bs4:
 python3-bs4 depends on python3-soupsieve; however:
  Package python3-soupsieve is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-bs4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-webencodings
 python3-psutil
 resetter
 python3-html5lib
 python3-lxml:amd64
 python3-soupsieve
 python3-bs4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Reinstall your OS.  There's no way to recover from removing the Python executable from the system without a TON of work and an external medium

Comment: I am not very sure if it would work, but if you have a Ubuntu installation media, you can copy the necessary files from `/usr/bin` as root.